# How can i install twilio package via pip?

Tags: python, twilio

I have **Python 2.7.12** (64 bit) installed on my Windows machine.
When I installed it, I added **pip** and the **python.exe** path. 
Now when I try to install **Twilio** with

```
pip install twilio
```

I get the error

```
pip is not recognized as an external or internal command
```

Comment: What operating system are you on?  Your system cannot find `pip` along its path, perhaps reboot?

Comment: What do you mean by "added pip and python.exe path"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: do you even have pip installed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include c:\python27\Scripts in SYSTEM PATH

Procedure to add c:\python27\Scripts to system path:

1. From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
3. Click the Advanced system settings link.
4. Click Environment Variables. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, add c:\python27\Scripts to the value of the PATH environment variable.(don't delete the existing ones)

Assumption: hoping your installation drive is C

Once you have added it, please close all command prompts and open a new command prompt and try it

Or in a new command prompt, type below command

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install twilio
```

**EDIT**:
If everything fails, try the below way:

Open command prompt, type "python -m pip install twilio" (without quotes).

Comment: how can i include c:\python27\Scripts in system path? as i am a new baby..

Comment: Added another method to install

Comment: Don't copy paste. It might copy some extra characters from here, please type in everything in command prompt.

Comment: yeh i aware of that .i tried several times but it shows same thing "invalid syntax"

Comment: ooh by the way c:\python27\Scripts; this path already exist in the path environment variable ( means where you suggest to add that)

Comment: Strange, Can you please try `python -m pip install twilio`

Comment: i also tried your last suggestion but it still showing "invalid syntax"

Comment: Open command prompt, type "python -m pip install twilio" (without quotes). Can you please post the complete error?

Comment: Thanks from my heart mate for your co-operation.its working

Comment: @squal my pleasure!! https://learnpythonthehardway.org this link will help you for python learning